# ESLint Warning: Use array destructuring

Tags: javascript, eslint

Why do I get the ESLint warning **Use array destructuring** for the following line?

```
tmpObj[item].sample = urls[key][0];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be having the [`prefer-destructuring`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring) flag on in your config. [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) was added as a part of ES6.

From the docs about the rule:

> With JavaScript ES6, a new syntax was added for creating variables from an array index or object property, called destructuring. This rule enforces the usage of destructuring instead of accessing a property through a member expression.

The rule considers this as incorrect:

```
// With `array` enabled
var foo = array[0];
// With `object` enabled
var foo = object.foo;
var foo = object['foo'];
```

And this as correct:

```
// With `array` enabled
var [ foo ] = array;
var foo = array[someIndex];

// With `object` enabled
var { foo } = object;
```

In your case, the below should do it. You are still accessing the first element this way.

```
[tmpObj[item].sample] = urls[key];
```

PS : You can always switch off the flag.