# How can I fix eslint: react/destructuring-assignment error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

```js
const Container = (props) => {
    return (
        <StyledDiv>
            <SmallScreenDiv>{props.children}</SmallScreenDiv>
        </StyledDiv>
    );
};
```

This is my code and error happens at {props.children} 
how can I fix this eslint error?

Comment: You have `prefer-destructuring` on in your ESlint. switch it off of destructure props. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69635125/eslint-warning-use-array-destructuring/69635305#69635305

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solution for this

1. Disable the prefer-destructuring feature on the eslint
2. destructure your props

   ```
    const Container = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <StyledDiv>
            <SmallScreenDiv>{children}</SmallScreenDiv>
        </StyledDiv>
    );
    };
   ```

or

```
   const Container = (props) => {
    const {children} = props
    return (
        <StyledDiv>
            <SmallScreenDiv>{children}</SmallScreenDiv>
        </StyledDiv>
    );
    };
```

I will recommend to use second option.

Answer (score 0):

You can also destruct your props like this:

```
const Container = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <StyledDiv>
            <SmallScreenDiv>{children}</SmallScreenDiv>
        </StyledDiv>
    );
};
```